# Render (screenshot) weapon model in Counter-Strike: Global Offensive

Tags: textures

I need to take screenshot of weapon model from screen like this, without any background. Tried to remove and change resources using `mat_texture_list` console command, but no success.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Honestly this looks close to the cleanest screenshot you could hope for. The model edges are crisp and well separated from the low-frequency blobs of the background, so it should be short work to lasso & magic wand the background out in your favourite image editing software. Is there a reason that won't serve your needs in this case?

Comment: I'd like to take this screenshots programaticaly, so I can't use image editing software each time. I think the model should be separated from other game content (background, text, etc.) using game engine, but I can't find console command or API interface to do it. Or just insert a background behind weapon model.

Comment: I have no idea if what you want exists... however, consider that you can process images programmatically. To be honest I would not worry too much about the background, but the text overlapping the model you want.